# I don't understand how to reach the last part of the problem

Tags: calculus

I feel like I am really close to the answer but I am not quite there. I would really appreciate some help with this question.

Assume that $0 < x < y$. Show that $x < \frac{(y-x)}{ln(y)-ln(x)} < y$ using the mean-value theorem.

I understand that the MVT states that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)$ and in this case we can set $f(x)$ to be $ln(x)$. This would look like so: $\frac{ln(y)-ln(x)}{y-x}$. So this would mean that the first equation,$\frac{(y-x)}{ln(y)-ln(x)}$, would be equal to $\frac{1}{f'(c)}$. Also, since $y>x$, then $\frac{(y-x)}{ln(y)-ln(x)}$ would always be positive. I just don't understand how to prove that $x < \frac{(y-x)}{ln(y)-ln(x)} < y$.

Comment: @KevinLong - Are you sure you mean $\big(\ln(c)\big)'$ and not $\ln'(c)$ ?

Comment: @mr_e_man You're right- I wrote it that way before, but felt it looked weird, but the way it is now is just wrong. I'll rewrite the post and repost it.

Comment: Remember that $c$ isn't just some value- the MVT says that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)$ for some $c$ in the interval $(a,b)$. As you pointed out, the expression that you're looking at is equal to $\frac{1}{f'(c)}$ for some such $c$. Also remember that you let $f(x)=\ln(x)$. Then what is $\ln'(c)$ equal to, and what can you then say about $\frac{1}{\ln'(c)}$?

Answer (score 1):

From MVT,

$$\frac{ln(y)-ln(x)}{y-x}=[ln(c)]’=\frac 1c$$
or,

$$ \frac{y-x}{ln(y)-ln(x)} = c$$

Since $x<c<y$, you get

$$x< \frac{y-x}{ln(y)-ln(x)} < y$$

Comment: Same problem from my last comment: $\ln(c)$ is a constant, so its derivative is $0$. This is exactly why we have the notation $f'=\ln'$ not referring to $x$ or $c$ (as opposed to $d/dx$, for example).

Comment: $[ln(c)]’$ is a shorthand for $[ln(x)]’|_{x=c}=\frac 1c$.

Comment: That's an abuse of notation. It should be written as $\ln'(x)$, not $\ln(x)'$, in my opinion. We are differentiating the function $\ln$, then evaluating it at some point $x$ or $c$.